# How to send file and json data in a http post request using angular 4?

Tags: angular

I am trying to send file and JSON data of the user details to the back end which node server in angular 4, I got some reference but nothing works.

> https://shazwazza.com/post/uploading-files-and-json-data-in-the-same-request-with-angular-js/

I have tried using to replicate the above-mentioned website, but I am not able to get a proper solution.
What I am getting is only I can send the file or only I can post the JSON data, but my question is to send them both in the same request using angular 4.

I have read many posts and tried few things but so far it was unsuccessful, could anyone suggest me how to do this?